# how to save group by columns added by user

Tags: javascript, post, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to javascripting and just started working on a requirement of kendo grid. The requirement is  when users drag and drop columns for grouping they want to save this grouping even after user logs out of the wpf application and comes back.

So can anyone suggest me if there is a way I can save this grouping somewhere so that I can refer to it every time I load the grid and show the data by last saved group by columns .

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by storing the preferences in browser cookies through JavaScript. You could track the positions of columns and store them in a cookie variable along with a user-id. Then, whenever the user access the page, you just retrieve the saved variable from cookie and get information and set the position of the columns accordingly.

JavaScript functions to set and get cookie

```
/*function to set/update a cookie variable.
 *@data is the data to be stored.
 *@key is the key value to the data.*/
function saveToCookie(data,key){

    /*setting cookie variable and expiry date/time*/
    var exdays=365
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(data) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = key+ "="+c_value

}


/*function to get a cookie variable.
 *@key is the key value to the variable*/
function getCookie(key){
    var cookies = document.cookie.match(key+'=(.*?)(;|$)');
    if (cookies) {

        return unescape(cookies[1]);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen DataGrid dataSource change event to get group information.

```
var groupingFields;

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        change: function(e) {
            // array of grouping objects
            groupingFields = this.group();
            console.log(groupingFields);
            // here you can check if grouping has changed
            // then you save changed groupings to cookies
        }
    },
    height: 550,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 200
    }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title"
    }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
    }, {
        field: "Country",
         width: 150
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");

// like this you can set grouping to grid datasource
function setGrouping(groups) {
    grid.dataSource.group(groups)
}
```